# How to use SettingsPane with MVVM Light in metro style app

Tags: windows-8, mvvm-light, microsoft-metro

I use MVVM Light Framework for a metro style app.

I want add a command in SettingsPane to show an about page. The about page should be displayed on the right (like preinstalled calendar app). For a test I have added following line in OnLaunched method in App.xaml.cs:

```
SettingsPane.GetForCurrentView().CommandsRequested += App_CommandsRequested;
```

and following event handler:

```
void App_CommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
{
    // Add an About command
    var about = new SettingsCommand("about", "About", (handler) =>
    {
        // show about page in flyout transition...
    });

    args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(about);
}
```

Is this the only way?
How can I flyout the about page? Any tips...?

Thanks for help!
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Michael, try using the SettingsFlyout control from the [Callisto project on github](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto)

You will need something like:

```
using Callisto.Controls;

//... other code here

//in your callback for handling the settings command:

// show about page in flyout transition...
var settingsFlyout = new SettingsFlyout();
settingsFlyout.Content = new AboutControl(); //this would be your own user control that contains the about page content

settingsFlyout.IsOpen = true;
```

Comment: Thanks, I use the SettingsFlyout from callisto!

Answer (score 2):

**to answer the first question:**
as far as I know, This is the only way to do something like that.

**To answer the second question:**
To flyout the the about page you can do this:

```
// Add an About command
var about = new SettingsCommand("about", "About", (handler) =>
{
    // show about page in flyout transition...
    var currentPane = new AboutPane(); // the aboutpane is a page
    var myPopup = new Popup();

    myPopup.IsLightDismissEnabled = true;
    myPopup.Width = _settingsWidth;
    myPopup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;

    myPopup.Width = 346;
    myPopup.Height = Window.Current.Bounds.Height;

    myPopup.Child = currentPane;
    myPopup.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, Window.Current.Bounds.Width - 346);
    myPopup.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, 0);
    myPopup.IsOpen = true;
});

args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(about);
```

I hope this will solve you're problem.